# Proper organisation of packages in java standard crud application

Tags: java, swing, package

I'm trying to make a small crud application using **swing**, with Authentication features and GUI.

Can you give me **the right organization and naming of my packages** ??

Comment: is there any standard normalization of java packages names like dao, test, gui ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no hard and fast rule, but the rule of thumb is to start with your company's domain name in reverse:

```
com.mycompany
```

Then add on the project:

```
com.mycompany.project
```

This ensures you're unlikely to have clashes between your classes and those from the libraries you depend on.

Then personally I try break things down by their functional groups, for example

```
com.mycompany.project.domain        // contains the business domain classes
com.mycompany.project.io            // contains the classes that deal with network or file-system
com.mycompany.project.persistence   // contains the classes that handle persistence of the business domain classes
com.mycompany.project.ui            // contains the user interface related classes
```

Within those packages, I might have further group but that would be very specific to the project.

The **important** thing is to be consistent across your project.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this is what i'm looking for, but i still don't have a right clarity on the content of packages io and domain.

Comment: I'll add some clarification

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: One package per module/feature, possibly with sub-packages. Put closely related things together in the same package. Avoid circular dependencies between packages.

Long answer: [I agree with most of this article](http://www.javapractices.com/topic/TopicAction.do;jsessionid=0BF4844350780B6F55476E1137FF4893?Id=205)